# How come some apps send notifications without background modes?

Tags: ios

I was using the Kijiji app where you can buy/sell things, and everytime someone replies to my ad I receive a notification on my screen. My understand is that unless you follow the background modes given by apple you can't do any notifications right? how is push notifications regularly handled by Apple, how does the app track in the background when someone has replied and then notifies me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While notifications can be sent from apps, they don't have to be. They can be sent from a backend service, which is probably what is happening here.

Comment: I just realized firebase for example has notifications for clients subscribed to topics, all the routing to the device is handled by Google. This is awesome to know I was actually really curious as to how this process was done.